# How to initialize/reset data structure array in C

Tags: c, data-structures, initialization

I have a data structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}EVENTS;

EVENTS newone[20];
```

Then I use newone somewhere. 
Now, I want to reset all values of newone[20] to 0.
Is there a short way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest way is to use [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)

```
memset(newone, 0, sizeof(newone));
```

Comment: You could initialise your array using `EVENTS newone[20] = {0,};` but you can't do `newone = {0,};` after the array has been declared.

Comment: Or if you can use compound literals: EVENTS *p = newone; p = (EVENTS[20]){{0,0,0},};